# Deploy endpoints 2.0 in an app engine old version isn't updating API explorer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm trying to update an app version AppEngine called "development" and was created with endpoints 1.0 with endpoints version 2.0.

When I update the "development" version with endpoints 2.0 and I go to API Explorer, the API Explorer still with the old version of the API (created with endpoints 1.0).

When I do the deploy in a new version called "development-endpoints2o" and I go to API Explorer, it works correctly.

Has anyone ever had this problem?
I think it's kind of cache problem or something. Is there any way to solve this?

I'm using python with endpoints 2.0.6.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've having this exact same issue!  Did you ever figure it out?  Also perhaps worth mentioning is that the API doesn't even work at all when it fails to show up in API Explorer, so I can't upgrade my existing service to endpoints 2.0 at all, which is quite a bit bigger problem than just not showing up in the API Explorer.  I assume the same for you?